# Find handles with a specific pattern

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, handles

I have some handles that look like:

```
ans = 

                    figure1: 189.0205
             sampleNameEdit: 17.0216
             selectCatPopup: 16.0237
             radiobutton_Al: 14.0266
              radiobutton_O: 190.0183
                     output: 189.0205
```

How can I easily look for those handles that start with `radiobutton__`? In the future, I will have many more radiobuttons that I would like to retrieve easily.

Comment: I think it'd help to show what line of code created that ans.

Answer (score 3):

To search for a specific pattern in a handle's name, the best approach would be to follow [Luis Mendo's advice in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630478/2778484).  However, consider searching based on the type of object you are looking for.  In this case, it would seem that all `radiobutton` objects need to be located.

The most straightforward way to find handles of for a certain style of [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html), is to search for handles with their [`Style` Property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html#f52-586852) set to `radiobutton`.   Consider a `figure` with two controls: a text box and a radio button, with their handles stored in an ordinary array `uih`:

```
hf = figure; % parent of uicontrols
uih(1) = uicontrol('style','text');
uih(2) = uicontrol('style','radiobutton');
```

Here are my test handle vales (yours will be different):

```
>> uih
uih =
    3.0012    4.0012
```

The first is the text box, and the second is the radio button.

### Search by parent handle

If you have the parent handle (i.e. the figure handle, `hf`), you don't even need the list of handles `uih`! Just call [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) as follows:

```
hr = findobj(hf,'style','radiobutton')
hr =
    4.0012
```

### Search handle array

If you don't have the parent handle, but do have a list of handles to search, that's no problem either:

```
hr = findobj(uih,'style','radiobutton')
hr =
    4.0012
```

### Search `struct` of handles

In your case, you have the handles stored as fields in a `struct`:

```
handles = 
    ht: 3.0012
    hr: 4.0012
hr = findobj(structfun(@(x)x,handles),'style','radiobutton')
hr =
    4.0012
```

Don't worry, this finds all radio buttons!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a struct with each handle stored in a different field:

```
s.radiobutton_1 = 1; %// example data: struct with several fields
s.otherfield    = 22;
s.radiobutton_2 = 333;

names = fieldnames(s); %// get all field names
ind = strmatch('radiobutton_',names); %// logical index to matching fields
selected = cellfun(@(name) s.(name), names(ind)); %// contents of those fields
```

returns the desired result:

```
selected =

     1
   333
```

Comment: The only corrent answer in my opinion

Comment: @RobertStettler You are right.  To search for any pattern, the other answers are not applicable.  However, the question is looking for radio buttons (objects with `'Style', 'radiobutton'`).  So while you only got your answer here, a downvote on the others seems a bit much.

Comment: @chappjc you are absolutely right, I already tried to undo the downvote but I got locked for some reason. I'll change that asap.

Comment: @RobertStettler  I've edited my post with a note about the difference in the answers and when each approach is applicable.  It should let you change a vote now, but of course that is your call.  :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear where you get that `ans` from and what its structure is, and what exactly is supposed to "start with" "radiobutton_". However, if you want to get handles to all existing radiobuttons, [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) is the way to go:

```
h = findobj(findobj('Type', 'uicontrol'), 'Style', 'radiobutton');
```

You can restrict the search to children e.g. of the current figure using

```
h = findobj(findobj(gcf, 'Type', 'uicontrol'), 'Style', 'radiobutton');
```

and you can restrict the search to a given list of handles `oh` (without children) using

```
h = findobj(findobj(oh, 'flat', 'Type', 'uicontrol'), 'Style', 'radiobutton');
```